# Как получить список файлов в папке resources в Java-проекте?

Tags: java, файлы

В своём проекте **projectDir/src/main/resources** я создал дополнительную папку **myFolderName**, в которой у меня лежат файлы `.xml`, и я хочу взять список файлов, которые лежат в этой папке.

Нашел вот такой код, но не знаю, какой путь нужно туда передать:

```
private static  List<String> getResourceFiles(String path) throws IOException {
    List<String> filenames = new ArrayList<>();

    try(
            InputStream in = getResourceAsStream(path);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)) ) {
        String resource;

        while((resource = br.readLine()) != null) {
            filenames.add( resource );
        }
    }

    return filenames;
}
```

Вопрос: каким образом я могу взять список файлов, которые лежат в директории 
**projectDir/src/main/resources/myFolderName** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
File dir = new File(path); //path указывает на директорию
File[] arrFiles = dir.listFiles();
List<File> lst = Arrays.asList(arrFiles);
```

Comment: хорошо, как мне туда передать относительный путь к папке < myFolderName > ?

Comment: String path = "src/main/resources/myFolderName". Вообще от IDE зависит

Answer (score 2):

Все разобрался, сделал так:

```
File dir = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("myFolderName").getFile()); 
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
```