# Как посчитать сколько в одной папке файлов .txt, и как с ними работать?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, у меня такой вопрос : когда работаешь с файлами, можно ли все фалы из одной папки, к примеру : у меня есть папка "Files", в которой хранятся три текстовых документах .txt, собственно сам вопрос - могу ли я все эти 3 файла считать и получить нужную информацию, к примеру мне в этих .txt 5 строчек, из каждого .txt мне нужно получить 2 4 5 строчку, и записать их значения отдельно, это возможно?
Можно ли будет определить точное количество файлов в этой папке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В библиотеке есть [удобный класс Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html), предоставляющий массу полезных методов для работы с файлами.

Получить ссылки на все файлы в директории:

```
Files.list(PATH).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Найти все ссылки на файлы .txt в директории:

```
Files.find(PATH, 1, (p, a) -> a.isRegularFile() && p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".txt")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Пример, как вывести 2,4 и 5 строчки всех файлов с раширением txt в заданной директории:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TestClass {
    public static final Path PATH = Paths.get("./testdir");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(Files.list(PATH).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        System.out.println(Files.find(PATH, 1, (p, a) -> a.isRegularFile() && p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".txt")).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        Files.find(PATH, 1, (p, a) -> a.isRegularFile() && p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".txt"))
                .forEach(p -> {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("File " + p.getFileName());
                        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(p);
                        System.out.println("2nd line: " + lines.get(1));
                        System.out.println("4th line: " + lines.get(3));
                        System.out.println("5th line: " + lines.get(4));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Результат работы:

```
[./testdir/2.txt, ./testdir/3.txt, ./testdir/1.txt, ./testdir/0.dxd]
[./testdir/2.txt, ./testdir/3.txt, ./testdir/1.txt]
File 2.txt
2nd line: 77777
4th line: 99999
5th line: 00000
File 3.txt
2nd line: 22222
4th line: 44444
5th line: 55555
File 1.txt
2nd line: 2222
4th line: 4444
5th line: 5555
```

Comment: Благодарю тебя )

Answer (score 1):

Получить список файлов в директории:

```
File dir = new File(path); //path указывает на директорию
File[] arrFiles = dir.listFiles();
List<File> lst = Arrays.asList(arrFiles);
```

[отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/638999/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-resources-%D0%B2-java-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5)